# Error al crear crear tabla intermedia

Tags: php, symfony

Utilizo symfony 5.0.4
Tengo una tabla cinema y otra user y necesito una intermedia.
Al realizar: sudo ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate siempre me salen los mismos errores que son los siguientes:

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 79:

An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE cinema-user (cinema_id INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_3FA689BCB4CB84B6 (cinema_id), INDEX IDX_3FA689BCA76ED395 (user_id), PRIM
  ARY KEY(cinema_id, user_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u
  ser (cinema_id INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_3FA689BCB4CB84B6 ' at line 1

In PDOConnection.php line 80:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u
  ser (cinema_id INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_3FA689BCB4CB84B6 ' at line 1

In PDOConnection.php line 75:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u
  ser (cinema_id INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_3FA689BCB4CB84B6 ' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está quejando de la sintaxis que hay en el nombre de la tabla "**-user...**"

para evitar el problema del error de sintaxis, puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

1) Cambia el nombre de la nueva tabla que quieres crear y en vez de **cinema-user**, llámala **cinema_user** con guión bajo (**_**) en vez del signo menos (**-**)

2) Si no pudieras cambiar el nombre de la tabla, porque no depende de ti, puedes poner el nombre entre **back-ticks** `cinema-user